# "Today's assumption" or "todays assumption" — which is valid grammar?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, nouns, possessives, apostrophe

We (non native English-speakers) are writing a paper and are wondering if the following construct is valid English:

> Yesterday's assumption is no longer valid.

Specifically the apostrophe after *yesterday* (and likewise in *today* and *tomorrow*) brings up some debate.

Can anyone give a clear answer whether this is proper English?

Comment: related: [Explanation on when the possessive should be used instead of an attributive noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14211)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The apostrophe indicates possession.

Without an apostrophe you are indicating plurality.

Since the point you are trying to convey is that the assumption you made *yesterday* is no longer valid, the apostrophe is appropriate.

> Yesterday's assumption is no longer valid.

It's kind of like saying *"The assumption of yesterday"*.

Answer (score 6):

It's absolutely necessary, to show that you mean *of yesterday*.  The alternative, *plural of yesterday*, is rare but does exist : "All our yesterdays have lighted fools/ the way to dusty death", Macbeth.

Comment: Upvote for quoting Shakespeare :-)

Comment: Absolute upvote for quoting Shakespeare :)

Answer (score -1):

Pedants would have it that 'yesterday' is not a person and therefore cannot own anything. They would suggest that the sentence be re-worded. "The assumption made yesterday... ."

Comment: Linguists would counter that genitive constructions are used for many things other than pure possession, and that the pedants’ point here is irrelevant.

Comment: Genitival construction did not appear to me to be of concern in the question raised. I apologise for any misunderstanding I may have caused.