# Ten years (of) experience

Tags: possessives

> IT professional with 10+ years **of** experience.

Do I need to put "of" between "years" and "experience"? I would have put it without any doubt if I hadn't read a few examples without "of" in the book [ACE the IT Resume: Resumes and Cover Letters to Get You Hired](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071492747)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*10+ years of experience* is proper. Units of time like *years* can also be used in a possessive sense, so you can also say *10+ years' experience*. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14211/explanation-on-when-the-possessive-should-be-used-instead-of-an-attributive-noun) and [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/should-two-weeks-vacation-be-two-weeks-vacation-possessive) for more details about that.

In formal writing you should not use *10+ years experience* without the apostrophe, but then you would not normally say "10+" in normal writing either. Résumé writing is a bit informal and has conventions of its own, such as frequent omission of articles and first person pronouns ("Implemented process that increased efficiency of widget production by 400 percent"). So you might be able to get away with *years experience* in that context. Still, you can't go wrong if you get it right: stick with either *years of experience* or *years' experience*.

Comment: If you wish to retain the possessive case, should not the equivalent of *ten years' experience* be *experience of ten years*? *The man's coat* is the same as *the coat of the man*. Saying *ten years of experience* is a bit like saying *the man of the coat*. I am no expert grammarian but I don't think *ten years of experience* is a simple possessive. I think it is an elliptical way of saying *ten-years' worth of experience*.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly may include the “of” and so indicate that experience is a thing *of* which you have a certain quantity, namely (more than) ten years. An alternative is to write “10+ years’ experience,” which actually turns the possessive or genitive relation completely around: if we were to reconvert the possessive “years’ ” into periphrastic genitive with “of,” we would wind up with the experience *of* more than ten years, rather than more than ten years *of* experience. But it is remarkable how very little difference in meaning that makes.

Comment: I agree and have said something similar in comment, independently of having read your answer. See below @phenry. Personally I don't believe *ten years of experience* is grammatically correct. Everyone knows what it means, and it doesn't matter. But strictly I think it is poor English. It is a bit like saying, as many do, 'a beauty of a landscape unfolded before my eyes*. The possessive is entirely misplaced. Correctly one would say *a beautiful landscape...*.